# Use variable of a JS script in Jade

Tags: javascript, socket.io, pug

I want to use a variable which I defined in a JS script in my jade file. Is that possible ?

To be clear enough, here's what I'm trying to do :

```
  script.
   var J1 = 0;
   var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:3000');
   socket.on('positionJ1', function(positionJ1) {
     J1 = positionJ1;
   })

p Le joueur 1 est en case #{J1}
```

EDIT :
To try the method with the DOM, I've done that, but I don't receive any alert.
It isn't the innerHTML method that doesn't work, because when I do document.body.innerHTML = "Something"; It works well.

```
script.
    var J = document.getElementById("posJ1").innerHTML;
    alert(J);

p#posJ1 Plop
```

Correction : It works when my p#posJ1 is above the script

Solution :

```
p#posJ1
   script.
    var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:3000');
    socket.on('positionJ1', function(positionJ1) {
      var J1 = document.getElementById("posJ1");
      J1.innerHTML = "Le joueur 1 est en case " + positionJ1;
      document.body.appendChild(J1);
    })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is literally impossible. Jade is rendered into static HTML before being served to the client. Whatever variables you put in are parsed at  the time of rendering only.

You're gonna have to go with javascript to do any run-time DOM manipulations like that.

```
  script.
   var J1 = 0;
   var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:3000');
   socket.on('positionJ1', function(positionJ1) {
     J1 = positionJ1;
     document.getElementById('position').innerHTML= J1;
   })

    p Le joueur 1 est en case 
        span#position
```

Comment: I tried your method but it seems that Jade doesn't recognize the ID. I did a little test, I join it in my question ;)

Comment: @Drarewyn Since the way HTML is parsed (top to bottom) and any javascript in it is run as it is found, any element has to be part of the dom before javascript operates on it. Your `J =` assignment and `alert()` runs right away, before `p` has had the chance to become part of the DOM. But socket method should work fine I guess, since it isn't run until it actually receives the message.

Comment: I manage to do what I want, your answers were very helpful, so thank you. 

I join my solution in my question ;)